# how to concat all non repeated characters using java 8

Tags: java, java-8

Want to get the non repeated characters in each word in a list and concat them to a new word using java 8:

Ex : [ non, repeated, character ]-> orpatdhte

Any hints ?

Comment: Forget about the list for once, try to solve this for a single word first, as the "now do a list" step seems entirely separate from that. Have you tried that? If so, please [edit] your question to show your attempt (even if it doesn't work).

Comment: The recommended approach for solving this kind of elementary interview question is to create a hash-set, add each character to it, (duplicates will be silently discarded,) then finally convert the hash-set to a list.

Comment: Does the order of the letters in the result matter?

Comment: @Bohemian yes it does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way to eliminate the duplicated letters from one word:

```java
public String removeDuplicates(String text) {
    Map<String, List<String>> charsVsCount = Arrays.stream(text.split(""))
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(c -> c, LinkedHashMap::new, Collectors.toList()));

        return charsVsCount.entrySet().stream()
                .filter(entry -> entry.getValue().size() == 1)
                .map(entry -> entry.getKey())
                .collect(Collectors.joining(""));
}
```

Now, if you have a list of words, you'll apply this logic for each of them, and, in the end, we'll merge them back together:

```java
var result = words.stream()
        .map(word -> removeDuplicates(word))
        .collect(Collectors.joining(""));

assertEquals("orpatdhte", result);
```

Comment: You haven't done what OP asks, which is **not** to get the *distinct* characters, but to **discard** *duplicated* characters. Your code does not pass the test you've coded.

Comment: yes, you are right, i have updated it now. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Because this is homework/interview question, I'll only provide pseudo code:

For each word:

- count the frequency of each letter, preserving the order encountered
- discard letters with a frequency greater than 1
- concatenate letters to result

There are multiple ways of coding this.

Note:  A `HashMap` won't help much due the requirement to preserve letter order, but there is another implementation of Map that is ideally suited.

Hint: It can be coded with a single line of code (albeit slightly long).

Answer (score 1):

I finally able to find a single liner for the above requirement ,

just to note i have used LinkedHashMap in the groupingBy clause inorder to maintain the sequence of non repeated characters

```
List<String> l = Arrays.asList("non", "repeated", "character");

System.out.println(l.stream().map(word ->   
    { return Arrays.stream(word.split("")).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),LinkedHashMap::new,Collectors.counting())).entrySet().stream().filter(e-> e.getValue()==1).map(e->e.getKey()).collect(Collectors.joining());
}).collect(Collectors.joining()));
```

Comment: That's very elegant. You can also remove the curly braces and `return` from the map-function, as it's a single line lambda.

Comment: Nice! `LinkedHashMap` is the correct choice. Purely style, but you can replace `map(e->e.getKey())` with `map(Map.Entry::getKey)`. In case you are actually starting with a sentence, you can start from that directly via: `Arrays.stream(sentence.split("\\W+"))`. The regex `\W+` means "non-word characters" so it will split on spaces/punctuation combos. By the way, it's perfectly fine to accept your own answer if it's the best answer (I think it is).

Comment: But you don’t have to use the Stream API for everything. After you collected into a `LinkedHashMap`, it’s more efficient to use `map.values().removeIf(count -> count != 1);` and `String.join("", map.keySet())` or replace `map` with `flatMap` and return `map.keySet().stream()` in this step and join them all with the final `.collect(Collectors.joining()))` step.